# how do i add an element with a key to th elist

Tags: python, list

let's say we have a list like:
`list = [{'name': 'car', 'number': '2'}]`

And i want to add `{'name': 'fruit', 'number': '4'}` element to it.

At the end list should look like:

```
list = [{'name': 'car', 'number': '2'},
        {'name': 'fruit', 'number': '4'}]
```

I tried to solve it like this:

```
list = [{'name': 'car', 'number': '2'}]
list.extend({'name': 'fruit', 'number': '4'})
```

but it returns: `[{'name': 'car', 'number': '2'}, 'name', 'number']`, and it's not what i want.
How do i do it?

Comment: Did you mean: `list.append({'name': 'fruit', 'number': '4'})`?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
list.append({'name': 'fruit', 'number': '4'})
```

The append() method adds the specified value to the end of the list.